# WebStorm/PhpStorm gives "Mismatched property value" error when using CSS lvh unit

Tags: css, intellij-idea, webstorm

## Using "new" CSS units causes a "Mismatched property value" error

I just started using these more modern CSS units, `lvh`, `svh` etc. But for some reason PhpStorm gives me this error. Since its a valid unit I expected it to work out of the box. Also this doesn't look like a linting error, normally there's some option to suppress if its a lint error.

Its the 2nd project that I have this issue with. Does anyone know if there's a setting or something that i can change so that these modern units are accepted by the IDE.

Thanks, see image with my error.

[image]

Comment: Please ALWAYS state versions of the tools used, in this case -- PhpStorm/WebStorm version.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is fixed since **2022.3 version** (2 major versions ago) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55824 . I've just checked in my PhpStorm **2023.1.4** in a plain `.css` file and `height: 100lvh;` is displayed just fine (in both `@supports` and actual property value).

Comment: *"Also this doesn't look like a linting error, normally there's some option to suppress if its a lint error."* That is because it comes from a lower Parser/Lexer level that is not suppressible (as it's a "more fundamental" syntax error in the IDE eyes).

Comment: Hey @LazyOne, thanks for the edit & the comments. I thought updates automatically happened, because normally i get notified but I just checked manually and it seems there's an update to do now. I'll post if its fixed.

Comment: @LazyOne, seems fixed, i feel like an idiot. thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. i'll keep a closer eye on my updates in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an year old or even older version... because accordingly to the [WEB-55824](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55824) ticket these `lvh` and other unites are supported **since 2022.3 version** (2 major versions ago, released on Dec 2022).

I've just checked your code sample in my PhpStorm 2023.1.4 in a plain `.css` file and `height: 100lvh;` is displayed just fine for me (inside the `@supports` and as the actual property value).

**Please upgrade your IDE.** The latest version is 2023.2.